# Deliver message to only one consumer from multiple subscribers

Tags: activemq-classic, message-queue

I am looking for a way to achieve this.

say I have 10 nodes subscribed to the same queue. one of them publishes the message. but I want the message to be delivered to only one node among all connected.

Further, that node will decide if it wants more nodes to process the same thing then it will again publish it and get extra help.

Is it even possible with ActiveMQ? if not, what else is suitable for this requirement?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the default behavior of an ActiveMQ queue. Just put the message there and one connected consumer will get it.

Don't confuse it with publish/subscribe, that is, topics. If you connect multiple subscribers to a topic, then all would get the same message.

Comment: I know that all subscribers will get the message, just wanted to check if there is any way in which we can select the destinations.

Comment: Like in Socket.IO, you can add selected clients into one room and send the message to them. and after the work is done, you can empty the room.

Comment: Ok, can you put some thoughts on this. not particularly using ActiveMQ . There are 10 nodes online. a job has been assigned, and each node, depending upon its capacity and H/W config will pick some part of the assigned job and leave rest for others, n starts processing.

Comment: kind of depends a bit what you mean with "part of a job". ActiveMQ just knows about messages. Typically, if you want to have something else than equal load balancing between clients, you need typically setup a unique queue for each client and somehow route the message there. There must be a way to solve your issue, not really sure I do understand it fully though

Comment: I can't use different queue for different client. I want to keep it scalable and dynamically distribute the load until the job is done.
Thanks anyways. I ll try to figure out what else I can do.